# Figure (composed of four subfigures) is not aligned

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to center and decrease the space between four images that are all part of one figure. Commands like `hspace` and `\captionsetup[sub]{skip=0mm}` do nothing. Moving my center so it's below \begin{figure} also just makes everything 1 long line.

Here's my relevant segment:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[b]
\vspace{-45mm}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Plot M37 with parameters to see more stars.png}
    \vspace{-10mm}
    \caption{Image of Open Cluster Messier 37}
    \vspace{-1mm}
    \label{fig:0}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{HD23190.png}
    \vspace{-10mm}
    \caption{Image of Star HD23190}
    \vspace{-1mm}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \vspace{-10mm}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{HD40649.png}
    \vspace{-10mm}
    \caption{Image of Star HD40649}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \vspace{-10mm}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{HD280264.png}
    \vspace{-10mm}
    \caption{Image of Star HD280264}
    \label{fig:3}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

And this is the result: [image]

Comment: Welcome! Your figure is simply too wide. `0.6\textwidth+0.6\textwidth>\textwidth`.

Comment: Why would that offset everything to the right?

Comment: @RobertF: There is a left margin against which your figures are flush, pushing the larger-than-`\textwidth` objects over into the right margin. Add `\usepackage{showframe}` to your preamble to see where the text block is situated and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: You *can* center oversized figures by either squeezing them in a narrow enough box or using `\centerline` etc. but this is not at all recommended.

Comment: @RobertF, basically, what Schrödinger's cat meant was "put 10 people in a small car, somebody will sit on the roof". There is only so much space in a page. If your pictures are too large, they won't fit that's all

Comment: Not central to the problem -- wrapping a float in `center` does nothing to or for the float.  It *does* add extra (probably unwanted) vertical space at the point of input.  Get rid of it.

Comment: Unfortunate. Do you have any idea as to why putting \hspace between my subfigures did not change the spacing at all? (It's not shown in my post, but when I had `\hspace{-10mm}` I got the same result as I posted)

Answer (score 1):

On this exemple, you can see something similar:
https://www.latextemplates.com/template/arsclassica-article

If you try to transpose, it could be a code like that:

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\subfloat[Image of Open Cluster Messier 37.]{\includegraphics[width=.45\columnwidth]{Plot M37 with parameters to see more stars.png}}\label{fig:0} \quad
\subfloat[Image of Star HD23190.]{\includegraphics[width=.45\columnwidth]{HD23190.png}\label{fig:1}\\
\subfloat[Image of Star HD40649.]{\includegraphics[width=.45\columnwidth]{HD40649.png}}\label{fig:2} \quad
\subfloat[Image of Star HD280264.]{\includegraphics[width=.45\columnwidth]{HD280264.png}}\label{fig:3}
\caption[Stars.]{Stars.}
\label{fig:PicturesOfStars}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Please also note, that there is a `}` missing in the second `\subfloat`. You might want to add it to make your example compilable.

Answer (score 0):

- newer insert float environment in a fix one (as are `minipage`, `center` etc)
- sum of sub figures widths in one row should be smaller than text width. If is not, than sub images spill out on right border
- in cases, when images have the same width as sub figures, use  of `\centering` command in subfigures have no sense, therefore you can dropout them
- since all images have the same width, it is handy to use `Gin` key for determining their widths,
- with option sub figure `[b]` are vertical aligned bottom of sub figures captions, this in the case if one of captions have more lines than others cause the top of images are not aligned
- if you use `\hfill` for horizontal space between images then images are pshed appart o left and right border of text

Considering above mentioned, the MWE with code of your images can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex, belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[htb]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Plot M37 with parameters to see more stars.png}
    \caption{Image of Open Cluster Messier 37}
    \label{fig:0}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{HD23190.png}
    \caption{Image of Star HD23190}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{HD40649.png}
    \caption{Image of Star HD40649}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{HD280264.png}
    \caption{Image of Star HD280264}
    \label{fig:3}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows part of page layout)